# Looking for an animated movie from the 70s or 80s involving aliens with many red orbs

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely remember watching an animated movie as a kid where the main protagonists, a man and a woman, are in some kind of a battle.

The thing that I remember the most are these slug like large aliens/insects/monsters that have red orbs all over their body. At some point the woman is wounded/killed and is healed/revied by the creatures. They did this by lifting her up with glowing tentacles.

Here is a crude drawing of the creature:
[image]

Comment: That pizza look delicious

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_(film)).

---

**A picture of the creature normally**
[image]

**Healing the title character with its [glowing tentacles](https://vimeo.com/186484833)**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is it. I'm pleasantly surprised that this looks much better than I remember, which is usually not the case. A big bonus that Hayao Miyazaki is involved :)